# update multiple rows using mysql stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

```
$UserId = $obj ["userid"];
$CalendarId = $obj ["arrayOfCalendarIdInStrings"];
$Calendars = explode ( ",", $CalendarId );
$Count = count ( $Calendars );
for($i = 0; $i < $Count; $i ++) {
                        // Update Query
            $query = "UPDATE calendars SET `isSelected` = '1' WHERE `calendar_id` = '$Calendars[$i]' AND  user_id='$UserId'";
            $update = mysql_query ( $query );
        }
```

How to Convert into Mysql Stored Procedure

Comment: Why convert a simple update statement into a stored procedure?

Comment: in a loop if there there are lot of record it can be slower

Comment: And you think it's gonna be faster when you put the stored procedure in the loop? You're wrong.

Comment: but how can we put in stored procedure?please help me in that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert your query to a stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myProcedure//
CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure (
  IN vCalendarID int(11),
  IN vUserID int(11)
)

BEGIN

 UPDATE calendars SET `isSelected` = '1' WHERE `calendar_id` = vCalendarID AND  user_id = vUserID;

END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Then in your php script you need to do the following:

```
$query = "CALL myProcedure('".$Calendars[$i]."','".$UserId."');";
$update = mysql_query ( $query );
```

Note that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead.